# How do you stop a fork bomb

Tags: linux, networking, system

How do you stop a fork bomb if you are already logged into a system?

Answer (score 6):

Sree,

If you still have "control" in shell, you can try a `ps` followed by a `grep`, and some `awk`, then a loop, to close all the processes including the parent.

Or manually...

If you're using `bash` for example, you have to identify the parent process first:

```
ps -ef | grep -i /bin/bash
```

and it should show you all `bash` processes running, in the third column you will see the parent process, you will see also that on multiple `/bin/bash` processes have the same parent process -- which we need to kill in our case  after you've identified the parent proc.

Just run a `kill -9 PARENTPROC`   (I don't recommend this if you don't feel comfortable :) with the parent proc.)

Or by name:

```
while :; do killall -9 processWithBombName; done
```

Basically you'll have to identify the process and kill it.

If you want to prevent a specific user from creating a fork bomb, you can limit it by taking a look at */etc/security/limits.conf*,
(you can do this on groups as well), inside you can append a line, something like:

```
Sree hard nproc 300
```

Which will limit user *Sree* to *300* processes.